# Discord.Py Error: Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found

Tags: discord.py

It Just Says The Error: Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found
And also it does not print the login idk why

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("yt!"))

TOKEN = os.environ['token']
client.run(TOKEN)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user}")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  ctx.reply("Test")
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) It's e because you define the function `test(ctx)` after running the `Bot` (`client`) with `client.run(<TOKEN>)`. Put that line (`client.run(<token>)` after defining all the functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found error in Discord Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478536/command-not-found-error-in-discord-python-code)

Answer (score -1):

`client.run` start before starting to get commands, to fix it, just put client.run into end of file line