# Unable to find command in python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have been going around in circles trying to resolve this issue, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have recently tried to improve my discord bot so that I can add additional functions to it soon, but in the process the bot is unable to find commands when requested any longer.

This is the bot.py file code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from constants import BOT_TOKEN, COMMAND_PREFIX

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.guilds = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=COMMAND_PREFIX, intents=intents)

bot.load_extension('cog.mod_cog')
bot.load_extension('cog.help_cog')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"Whoops, looks like I couldn't find that command, {ctx.author.mention}!")
    else:
        raise error

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

This is the mod_cog.py file where the commands are located:

```py
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/Discord_Bot")
from utils import save_warnings, load_warnings

class ModCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.warnings_dict = load_warnings()

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Owner", "Support Team")
    async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason: None):
        if reason == None:
            reason = "This user was banned by " + ctx.message.author.name
        await member.ban(reason=reason)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Owner", "Support Team")
    async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason: None):
        if reason == None:
            reason = "This user was kicked by " + ctx.message.author.name
        await member.kick(reason=reason)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Owner", "Support Team")
    async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        if reason is None:
            reason = f"This user was warned by {ctx.message.author.name}"

        user_id = str(member.id)
        self.warnings_dict[user_id] = self.warnings_dict.get(user_id, 0) + 1
        save_warnings(self.warnings_dict)

        warning_count = self.warnings_dict[user_id]
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been warned for: '{reason}'. This is warning number **{warning_count}**.")

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Owner", "Support Team")
    async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, timelimit):
        timelimit_lower = timelimit.lower()
        if "s" in timelimit_lower:
            gettime = timelimit_lower.strip("s")
            if int(gettime) > 2419000:
                await ctx.send("The mute time amount cannot be longer than 28 days")
            else:
                newtime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(gettime))
                await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + newtime)
        elif "m" in timelimit_lower:
            gettime = timelimit_lower.strip("m")
            if int(gettime) > 40320:
                await ctx.send("The mute time amount cannot be longer than 28 days")
            else:
                newtime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(gettime))
                await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + newtime)
        elif "h" in timelimit_lower:
            gettime = timelimit_lower.strip("h")
            if int(gettime) > 672:
                await ctx.send("The mute time amount cannot be longer than 28 days")
            else:
                newtime = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(gettime))
                await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + newtime)
        elif "d" in timelimit_lower:
            gettime = timelimit_lower.strip("d")
            if int(gettime) > 28:
                await ctx.send("The mute time amount cannot be longer than 28 days")
            else:
                newtime = datetime.timedelta(days=int(gettime))
                await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + newtime)
        elif "w" in timelimit_lower:
            gettime = timelimit_lower.strip("w")
            if int(gettime) > 4:
                await ctx.send("The mute time amount cannot be longer than 28 days")
            else:
                newtime = datetime.timedelta(weeks=int(gettime))
                await member.edit(timed_out_until=discord.utils.utcnow() + newtime)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ModCog(bot))
```

No matter what I change, I seem to get the same result with the bot telling me that the command cannot be found.

I have tried changing the file pathing for the mod_cog.py file from "cog.mod_cog" to the direct file path "...Desktop/Discord_Bot" still no change.

I have checked the indentations and even spend a good few hours running it through AI to try and resolve the issue, but I just keep going in circles.

I have ensured that bot.run() is in the last line. I have added the await bot.process_commands(message) line as mentioned in other suggestions, but still getting the same outcome. The bot cannot find any of the commands.

I'm not sure if I'm going wrong with the pathing to the mod_cog.py file or what. I've tried different variations of pathing the file. I just can't get it for whatever reason to find the command. Any support would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found error in Discord Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478536/command-not-found-error-in-discord-python-code)

Comment: It there any output aside from 'not finding command'? 
Also, are you running the bot out of a VENV where your mod_cog.py lives as you are adding that directory to path?